# Помогите с ошибкой Unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin

```
package com.example.android.justjava


import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import java.text.NumberFormat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

        fun submitOrder(view: View) {
        int numberOfCoffees 2
        display(numberOfCoffees)
        displayPrice(numberOfCoffees * 5)
    }


    fun display(number: Int) {
        val quantityTextView = findViewById<View>(R.id.quantity_text_view) as TextView
        quantityTextView.text = ("" + number)
    }


    private fun displayPrice(number: Int) {
        val priceTextView = findViewById<View>(R.id.price_text_view) as TextView
        priceTextView.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number))
    }
         }
```

Выдаёт ошибки

```
Error:(32, 9) Unresolved reference: int
Error:(33, 17) Unresolved reference: numberOfCoffees
Error:(34, 22) Unresolved reference: numberOfCoffees
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
```

Вот в этой части кода, 
 int-Не разрешённая ссылка
 И имя переменной "numberOfCoffees" - так же не разрешённая ссылка. К какой документации стоит обратиться, чтобы узнать об этом больше?

```
 fun submitOrder(view: View) {
    int numberOfCoffees 2
    display(numberOfCoffees)
    displayPrice(numberOfCoffees * 5)
```

Comment: Опишите свою проблему конкретно. Здесь не форум гадалок

Comment: @BogdanBida Как указать переменную, что бы она была допустимой и в какой части кода?

Comment: что это за 2 в вакууме? может `val numberOfCoffees = 2` ?

Comment: У вас в коде на Kotlin  вставки на Java ))         int numberOfCoffees 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все переменные в котлине объявляются через ключевые слова `val` или `var`, с опциональным в некоторых случаях указанием типа после имени переменной через двоеточие. Т.е. например так:

```
val numberOfCoffees:Int = 2
```

У вас же явная попытка написать в `Java` стиле (тип переменной перед её именем), причём с пропуском `=`. Ну и ещё в котлине не примитивов как таковых и все типы с большой буквы пишутся, включая `Int`